# Eclipse issue - View not getting displayed properly

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse is not opening the java files properly even after a restart. Could you please let me know on what is to be done

[image]

Comment: Try starting Eclipse with `-clearPersistedState` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uninstalling eclipse, restarting PC, and then reinstalling eclipse. If that doesn't work try making sure that your graphics drivers are up to date. Lastly you may report the bug and/or search for a similar bug at [eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with eclipse supporting file,you have missed some of the files
just delete Eclipse and download it once again it will work perfectly i did the same its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

go to **eclipse > Window > Reset Perspective** ...hope this will resolve your issue

Comment: The above steps are not resolving my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **Window -> New Window** and close the old window. Restart Eclipse.